# jenkins execute shell failed with error: Could not find lane 'ios release

Tags: jenkins, fastlane

my shell code:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
ls -al
cd NIMDemo/
ls -al
bundle install

bundle exec fastlane release
```

when i clicked Build Now button on jenkins, build failed with error:

```
bundle exec fastlane $'release\E'
[16:05:31]: [32m------------------------------[0m
[16:05:31]: [32m--- Step: default_platform ---[0m
[16:05:31]: [32m------------------------------[0m
+------------------+-----+
|      [33mLane Context[0m      |
+------------------+-----+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios |
+------------------+-----+
[16:05:31]: [31mCould not find lane 'ios release'. Available lanes: ios release, ios tests[0m

+------+------------------+-------------+
|           [32mfastlane summary[0m            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[16:05:31]: [31mfastlane finished with errors[0m
[31m
[!] Could not find lane 'ios release'. Available lanes: ios release, ios tests[0m
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

my `Fastfile` code:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

desc "upload appstore lane"
  lane :release do

  end

  lane :tests do
    run_tests(scheme: "MyAppTests")
  end
end
```

code `bundle exec fastlane release` ran ok when i typed it into the terminal on the mac jenkins deployed.

[ran result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0pb5.png)

What can i do to work out it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you try changing your script to `bundle exec fastlane ios release`? Is it normal that the first line of output has `$'` and `\E'` wrapped around the word `release`? If this is sent to fastlane, this could explain why it doesn't find a lane of that name (but is not correctly outputting that then in the error message, which makes it a bit nonsensical)

Comment: @janpio That's amazing, things worked as you said. Thank you very much for answering my puzzle! Furthermore. Why Jenkins attached '$' and '\E' to my script, is it reasonable?

Comment: I don't know enough about Jenkins to assess that.

Comment: @janpio That's all right. Anyway, thank's for reply.